# Uppercase accented characters in perl

Tags: perl, uppercase

Is there a way to uppercase accented characters in perl,

```
my $string = "éléphant";

print uc($string);
```

So that it actually prints ÉLÉPHANT ?

My perl script is encoded in ISO-8859-1 and $string is printed in an xml file with the same encoding.

Comment: Just ran this one-liner (using UTF-8), and it worked as expected: `perl -Mutf8 -E'binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; say uc "éléphant"'` The `use utf8` tells perl that the source code is non-ASCII but Unicode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`perl` only understands US-ASCII and UTF-8, and the latter requires

```
use utf8;
```

If you want to keep the file as `iso-8859-1`, you'll need to decode the text explicitly.

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(locale)';
use Encode qw( decode );

# Source is encoded using iso-8859-1, so we need to decode ourselves.
my $string = decode("iso-8859-1", "éléphant");
print uc($string);
```

But it's probably better to convert the script to UTF-8.

```
use utf8;  # Source is encoded using UTF-8
use open ':std', ':encoding(locale)';

my $string = "éléphant";
print uc($string);
```

If you're printing to a file, make sure you use `:encoding(iso-8859-1)` when you open the file (no matter which alternative you use).

Comment: Ok, I realize that i might have omitted an important point. $string is actually the result of a parameter called using the CGI package. my $string = param('word1'); So I might actually have to encode $string in ISO-8859-1

Comment: Use method 1, then. And you must encode when writing to the XML no matter which method you use. (I mentioned this at the bottom.) Always decode inputs, always encode outputs.

Comment: Thanks, @ikegami: I don't know why, but I get the error "Can't locate object method "BINMODE" via package "TMInput" when I use the "use open" line. However, it works when only using: `code` use utf8; use Encode qw( decode );
my $word1 = decode("iso-8859-1", param('word1')); print uc($word1);`code`

Comment: No mention on TMInput on cpan or google. No idea what you did.

Comment: Since this is latin1-specific, it will fail on 99% of UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger, Are you saying a program designed to decode latin-1 doesn't work if you pass it UTF-8 instead of latin-1? Well, yeah, [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
use Encode qw/encode decode/;

my $enc = 'utf-8'; # This script is stored as UTF-8
my $str = "éléphant\n";

my $text_str = decode($enc, $str);
$text_str = uc $text_str;
print encode($enc, $text_str);
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
ÉLÉPHANT
```